# LC3 Concatenate and Compare Strings

Tags: string, lc3

I am writing an LC-3 file that should be able to: get the length of a string, copy a string, concatenate two strings, and compare two strings.
I believe I have the string length and string copy subroutines done correctly, but the last two are giving me a lot of trouble. I *think* what I have should work but it is not, I have tried changing things around and testing, but unfortunately nothing I do is working.

I am just going to post my code in a GitHub Gist with comments detailing exactly what I think should happen, if anyone has the time to check it out and offer advice on what is going wrong and how to fix it, I would appreciate.

Wish I had a more specific question to ask but I just have no idea where to go from where I am.

Here is the file: https://gist.github.com/Skipeeto/6179d4c8cf732a72a64b733c3e2a1891#file-string-asm

Answer (score 0):

I did not know GETS was a valid LC-3 macro? If I may ask, what tool are you using to compile and run this code?

Jeff

Comment: It is a version of the lc3 simulator but modified for CAU students, maybe that is way. I think all the code is working right except the strcat and strcmp subroutines.  Here is a link to it http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~fsieker/TestSemester/assignments/LC3CSU/doc/index.html